# How to write down the probability space of this stochastic process

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider infinitely repeated coin-toss. Then the probability space can be written as $\Omega=\{H,T\}^\infty$ with its product $\sigma$-algebra. Now let's assume that after each round, there is positive probability that the whole process ends. Then what is the probability space?

I construct it in this way. Let $$\Omega=\Big(\{H,T\}\times\{0,1\}\Big)^\infty.$$ Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the subset of $\Omega$ that contains sets of the following forms: $(x_1,1,x_2,1,\cdots,x_n,1)\times \Omega$ and $(x_1,1,x_2,1,\cdots,x_n,0)\times \Omega$. Then define $\mathscr{F}$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{G}$. Then $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ represents the coin-toss process with termination. The idea is that once it terminates, there will be no future flip. Hence the event $(x_1,0,x_2,1)$ is not measurable, where $0$ means termination while $1$ means continuation.

Am I right? Is there any better ways to represent this process?

Comment: What is a round?